# how to stay connected to the server

Tags: android, json, url, connection, android-volley

I'm trying to stay connected with a url but I don't know how.
I'm working on a quiz app so I need to refresh the question every time that user lose or win.

but it **takes long time** to connect to the url every time.
so I just want to connected once and then just get new questions from that url.
I'm using volley library to connect to a url.

And This is my code.

```
public static void getQuestionsData(Activity activity, 
OnDoneLintenter onDoneListener) {
String url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=15&type=multiple";
RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = 
new JsonObjectRequest(ColumnStructure.GET, url, null,
  jsonObject -> {
    try {
      JSONArray array 
      = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ColumnStructure.COL_RESULTS);
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        setColumnStructureFields(array, i);
      }
      onDoneListener.onDone();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.e("Log", "there is not result : " + e.getMessage());
    }
  },
  volleyError -> {
    Log.e("Log", "volley error : " + volleyError.getMessage());
  });
 queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

I use this code at the beginning and every time user lose or win.So is there any way to stay connected with the url or at least get the json faster.

Comment: You can use WebSocket

Comment: If you have any tutorial please leave the link here@MaverickFabroa